# Kafka Connect failed to add MySqlConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I need someone's help.

I follow a tutorial [Streaming Data from MySQL into Kafka with Kafka Connect and Debezium](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/) but I have the trouble connecting MySql to Kafka server using Debezium MySQL Connector.

Here is my setup and other information.

OS : Windows 10.

Kafka Connect : [Confluent 5.0](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-confluent-platform-5-0/).

MySQL Connector : 0.8.1 Final.

I keep files

[image: here].

I add the plugins path

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

When I tried connecting to Kafka Connect, It returned me an error.
"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector"

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Am I missing something? Anyone can help?

Comment: If you have added the connector while kafka-connect was already up and running then you either need to load the connector manually, or restart kafka-connect

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I already restart kafka Connect server but the result still the same.

Comment: You need to put the jar file under `plugins.path` which is defined in kafka-connect properties which usually points to `/usr/share/java`

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I have put all the plugin folders in the custom path and i already add the path in the kafka-connect properties file according to Picture 1 and Picture 2.

Comment: As I said, place only the jar file under /usr/share/java.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Works like a charm. Thank you. Btw, what is the reason why we have to add those Jar files in that folder despite we have pointed the plugin path already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've placed the .jar connector file under `plugins.path` which is defined in kafka-connect properties and usually maps to `/usr/share/java`.

After adding the connector under the correct directory you need to either load the connector or restart kafka-connect so that it is automatically loaded in start-up.

Comment: As the Picture 1 I set the plugin.path which map to 2 directories but why It does not map to those path?

Comment: Why do you want to put that jar file in another directory?

Comment: Since I read the documentation about add plugins. I understand that we can use the customized directory then we have to add the customized path in the properties file. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Same doubt about placing jar in another directory . @W.Phromma you got some idea  ?And which jar we should copy ?

Answer (score 0):

your plugin path is wrong (confluent-5.0.0\share\java)
either it should start with / (which means root of current drive) or you should give complete path.

This is the reason connector jar is not present in classpath